# WebServices using ZendFramework 2

Tags: android, web-services, rest, zend-framework2

How to write RESTful WebServices to Android Application using ZendFramework 2?
The request and response data format is JSON only.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to use : [Zend Expressive](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-expressive/), wich is the micro-framework from Zend, also is compatile with all Zend Framework modules and the most important part, and reason why I use it is because is very similar to Zend Framework 2

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apigility, it's a lib to create RESTful API using ZF2: 
https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility